# How can I show url video in my blog as video that you can play and pause?

Tags: html, blogger

My question is clear I want code that make any download link of video show as video  in my blog at blogger , for example I have this code but I show only videos that end with 'm4v' but i need one that work also with 'mp4' videos so  :

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" height="360" src="https://mdn.illops.net/japanesepod101/V_S1L9_121230_jpod101.m4v" width="640"></iframe><br />
```

but this one not working :

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" height="360" src="https://bingoserver.pw/s1/Anime/Ended/Gunparade%20March%20Arata%20Naru%20Kougunka/Gunparade.March%20ArataNaru.Kougunka.01.[480p-DVD].Dual.Audio.takanime.biz.mkv" width="640"></iframe><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `<video>` HTML Tag should do the trick.

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

```html
<video 
  controls
  src="https://mdn.illops.net/japanesepod101/V_S1L9_121230_jpod101.m4v">
</video>
```